# How to print a list in the format of a set. In Python3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, printing, set

I need to print the elements of a list in the form of a set. So if I have the list [1,2,3] the print statement needs to return {1,2,3}.

Comment: Do you mean you need to make all lists look like sets, or just one in particular? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. It had to do that for any list. @msngupta got what I couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is

```
s=[1,2,3]
print("{"+str(s)[1:-1]+"}")
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I needed. Sorry for not posting what I had already but I was completely lost on how to implement this and didn't really have much to go on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way (where `x` is your list):

```
>>> print("{" + ', '.join(str(item) for item in x) + "}")
{1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: I'd use `repr(item)` rather than `str(item)` to make the formatting match completely. It won't matter for integers but will for other things like strings and floats. Edit: I didn't notice this was Python3, forget what I said about floats. Still counts for strings though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want specific formatting, you will need to write that yourself.

Here is a subclass of `set` that implements that format:

```
class Myset(set):
    def __str__(self):
        return '{'+','.join(repr(e) for e in sorted(self))+'}'

print Myset([1,2,3]) 
# {1,2,3}
```

Or, just use Python 3x:

```
>>> print(set([1,2,3]))
{1, 2, 3}
```

The order may be different, however, without the `sorted` that I used above...

Answer (score 1):

If you want a set, why not turn the list into a set? With `x` being your list:

```
>>> x=[1,2,3]
>>> x_set=set(x)
>>> print(x_set)
{1, 2, 3}
```

It's noteworthy that sets are not ordered and cannot contain duplicates. (But then again what is the benefit of printing something to look 'like' a set, but is not?)

```
>>> x=[1,2,3,3,4]
>>> x_set=set(x)
>>> print(x_set)
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Comment: That works as long as there are no duplicates in the list, and you don't care about order.

Comment: Yes, it's probably noteworthy that sets are not ordered.

Comment: Only in Python3 -- Python 2 will print `set([1, 2, 3])`

Comment: But the title of the question reads "Python 3". And my answer hints the syntax of Python 3, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
("{{{}}}".format(",".join(map(str,l))))
{1,2,3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend the class from `list` and override `__repr__` method

```
class List(list):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "{%s}"%(",".join([str(each) for each in self]))

l = List()
l.append(1)
l.append(2)
print l

{1,2}
```